express-session not persisting when deployed in vercel
I'm using express-session and MemoryStore while deploying on Vercel. Although it generates an authentication cookie and sets it in the client, upon sending another request or refreshing, it redirects to the login page.
index.ts
const store = MemoryStore(session);

app.set("trust proxy", 1); // in production
app.use(
    session({
        name: "auth",
        secret: "secret",
            proxy: true, // in production 
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5,
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "none", // in production
            secure: true, // in production
        },
        resave: false,
        store: new store({
            checkPeriod: 1000 * 60 * 60,
        }),
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);

However, in production, it's generating new session IDs and in dev it works flawlessly
verify.ts
    const session = req.session as any;
    if (!session.authenticated) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }

I want the authorized sessions to persist in production. How can I achieve this?
